# Application installed using Wine cannot be uninstalled

Tags: 14.04, wine, software-installation

Recently I installed Advanced System Care 7.2 in my Ubuntu 14.04 using Wine. I installed it to know how to use Wine, since it was the first time I was using it. After the installation I tried to uninstall it, but I can't.

2 software named 'IOBit Uninstaller' and 'Surfing Protection' also get installed along Advanced System Care. I removed those 2 software using Wine, but cannot remove Advanced System Care. Why can't I remove and how can I remove it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have any other software running under wine, you could just remove all the wine folder hidden on your $HOME directory by entering in a terminal:

```
rm -rvf $HOME/.wine
```

The folder will be recreated next time you try to install other programs in wine so don't worry. But if  you don't like this option, you can just search the file structure for the program and delete its folder:

```
nautilus $HOME/.wine/drive_c
```

Your program should be in "Program Files" or some usual Windows location like that. After that, if you want to remove icons generated by the installer, you can find them somewhere there:

```
nautilus $HOME/.local/share/applications/wine
```